# groovy: Caught: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found even if use @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, groovy

I have this test code to connect to a SQL Server:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='com.microsoft.sqlserver', module='mssql-jdbc', version='9.2.1.jre8')
import groovy.sql.Sql

def server = '10.6.6.1'
def port = '1433'
def user = 'sa'
def password = 'somepassword'

def url = "jdbc:sqlserver://${server}:${port};databaseName=master;"

Sql.withInstance(url, user, password) { sql ->

    def serverName = sql.firstRow('SELECT @@SERVERNAME')

    assert serverName[0]

}
```

if I run it I get:

> Caught: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://10.6.6.1:1433;databaseName=master;
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://10.6.6.1:1433;databaseName=master;
> at test.run(test.groovy:12)

the jar for the driver is downloaded by Grape for sure because inside subdirectories in `.groovy/` directory in my home dir I can find it.

But no way I am not able to connect to the server.

I am using groovy 3.0.9 but I tried with older versions and it's the same.

Edit:

If I add to the code before connecting:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

It works, but it's very strange, I was sure that this is not necessary anymore.
If someone can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it still required to register sql driver in `java.sql.DriverManager`

every jdbc driver contains approximately the following code usually in `XyzDriver` class:

```
static {
    try {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver( new XyzDriver() )
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

the same for microsoft sql driver: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/09d35bfc2338f1fc7c41a958d1e627fa0d6a2b65/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java#L732

that's why you have to call a code like `Class.forName("XyzDriver")` to make driver self-register in `DriverManager`

---

**UPD: JDBC 4.0 / java8+**

from javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` ...

When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.

mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar is 4.0 compatible. it contains `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` in `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file

however let's check DriverManager code and how it looks up for drivers:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#l100

```
static {
    loadInitialDrivers();
    println("JDBC DriverManager initialized");
}
```

`DriverManager` tries to find drivers at the moment it's loaded. so, jdbc driver must be present in classpath at app startup to be auto-registered.

and it's not the case with @Grab in code.

as workaround after grab you could do this to call self-register for all drivers:

```
ServiceLoader.load(java.sql.Driver.class).iterator().findAll()
```

Comment: From what I read here on "Autoloading of JDBC drivers" https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html  if the driver is jdbc 4.x driver the `Class.forName(driver)` should not be needed anymore. This is related to apache derby but the point is the jdbc 4.x driver version.

Comment: About your last edit, when you say "jdbc driver must be present in classpath at app startup. and it's not the case with @Grab in code."  I was thinking this was related to `GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)`  so it is not the purpose of this setting ?

Comment: the purpose of `systemClassLoader` - to use a system class loader (instead of groovy class loader). but it's not about when to execute this. without `systemClassLoader` the `DriverManager` can't even see downloaded driver-artifacts.